# How To Access Google Calendar Access Token using Username and Password from Node server

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, calendar

I am trying a post-call to generate an access token using the client username and password. I would like to know how we can achieve this through Node Js Code.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, `access_token` are rattached to the [OAuth2 authentication framework](https://oauth.net/2/), which doesn't require the application owner (you) to have access to one of your user email/password. This is a more secure approach that is broadly adopted.

The way OAuth2 works on the Google Calendar API is a 3-parties (or 3-legged) authorization. Let's take the example of a user that browses your website and want to sign-in using its Google Account. The steps to authenticate him are the following:

1. The user clicks on "Sign-in with Google"
2. The application owner (you) performs a request to Google saying that a user wants to connect (that's the OAuth consent screen)
3. Google replies by giving you a URL (`authorizationUrl`) where to redirect the user
4. On that URL, the user is prompted with several information about your application and can grant access.
5. When the user has granted access, Google will redirect the user to your application success page (`callbackUrl`) with a unique code.
6. Using that code, the application can retrieve an `access_token`, which temporarly lets your application performs requests **on behalf of a user**.

These steps are a rapid overview of the OAuth-flow, also known as the OAuth dance. To make `POST` requests to the Google Calendar API, you will have to perform that OAuth dance for every single of your users.

Implementing that flow can be tricky. Fortunately, [Google gives very helpful documentation on that](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). If you don't want to bother, you can also use API-tools (like [Pizzly](https://github.com/bearer/pizzly)) that takes care of that for you.